# Stata: Hiding command lines

Tags: stata

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. di "I am getting some summary statistics for PRICE"
I am getting some summary statistics for PRICE

. su price

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
       price |        74    6165.257    2949.496       3291      15906

. 
end of do-file
```

I want to hide the command lines, and show only the results as follows:

```
I am getting some summary statistics for PRICE

        Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
    -------------+--------------------------------------------------------
           price |        74    6165.257    2949.496       3291      15906
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: The output text file (quiet_noise. txt) will have the one you want.

```
quietly {
     log using quiet_noise.log, text replace
     sysuse auto
     noisily: di "I am getting some summary statistics for PRICE"
     noisily: su price
     log close
}
```

Comment: Another option, if you are willing to try something a bit more fancy, is to go for [the "knitr" approach to do-files](https://github.com/amarder/stata-tutorial), which mixes Markdown-formatted text with Stata code.

Answer (score 11):

The answer from user1493368 is correct, but writing code like that is tedious and error-prone for more complicated examples. Another answer is just to learn how to write Stata programs! Put this in a do-file editor window and run it

```
program myprog 
    qui sysuse auto, clear
    di "I am getting some summary statistics for PRICE"
    su price
end
```

Then type interactively

```
myprog
```

As in practice one makes lots of little mistakes, a very first line such as

```
capture program drop myprog
```

is a good idea.

This really is prominently and well documented: start with the later chapters in [U].

Answer (score 4):

Commenting Stata output, especially when you want to share your logfiles become a problem which is very well reflected in your question.

As Nick Cox nicely has explained, Writing a program to display the text is a very good idea. However, including text in a program comes at a cost i.e. you cannot use that program with other variables. For example, if you write a program to run a regression with the given variables, you cannot use that program with other variables if you comment the findings. In other words, writing comments about a particular findings will make the program less useable. As a result, you will end up writing a program for each analysis, which is not that appealing.

So what is my suggestion? Use the **[MarkDoc](http://www.haghish.com/statistics/stata-blog/reproducible-research/markdoc.php)** pakcage to comment your results.

In MarkDoc (ssc install markdoc) you can write comments using Markdown / HTML /LaTeX and have it exported to a dynamic document within Stata. In your example it would be as follows:

```
    qui log using example, replace

    sysuse auto, clear

    /***
    Writing comments in Stata logfiles
    ==================================

    I am getting some summary statistics for PRICE
    ***/

    summarize price

    qui log c
    markdoc example, replace export(pdf)
```

And MarkDoc will produce a PDF for you that has interpreted your comments as Markdown. In addition to **pdf**, you can convert the same log file to other formats such as **docx**, **html**, **tex**, Open Office **odt**, **slide**, and also **epub**.

The PDF and HTML formats will also have a syntax highlighter for Stata commands, using [Statax Syntax Highlighter](http://www.haghish.com/statax/statax.php).

Comment: The assertion that a program cannot be used for other variables applies only to programs that wire in dependence on particular variables. It's nonsense otherwise: a competently written program makes no assumptions about variable names. Stata commands could hardly work otherwise.

Comment: I can only agree with your comment. Perhaps I was not clear enough. I pointed out one shortcoming of writing a comment in a program if we want to use that program over and over with other variables or in different occasions. In situations like that, having a comment about a particular finding would make that program unusable in other occasions. Apart from that, there is no problem with writing smaller problems.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess we are in basic agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to run your log within a loop. When you run a loop the code is displayed once in the result window then only the output is displayed. So for instance if you do as follow:

```
foreach z in 1 {
    log using "myfile"
    di "I am getting some summary statistics for PRICE"
    su price
    log close
}
```

The content of the foreach will be displayed in the result and when the log will only keep the results of the commands.